# encode php object into json

Tags: javascript, php, json

There is alot on this subject but I can't figure out why it's not working, it was, now it stopped. I run a query and return an object with php, then try to encode it to json, then parse it client side to json. It is telling me that SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data.

My php code:

```
$product = ShoppingCart::addToCart($_GET['product_id']);

echo json_encode($product);
```

client side code:

```
$.get(
    './models/shoppingCart.inc.php',
    {product_id: id},   
    function(data) { 
        var product = JSON.parse(data)

        $('#cart_qty').html(cartQty);

        var table=document.getElementById("table_products");
        var row=table.insertRow(1);
        var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
        cell1.innerHTML=product.product_name;
        cell2.innerHTML=product.price;
        cell3.innerHTML=qty;

    },
    'html' 
);  

};
```

this is what is getting returned:

```
16{"product_id":"16","product_name":"Pavlova","price":"17.4500","supplier":{"company_name":"Pavlova, Ltd.","address":"74 Rose St.\r\nMoonie Ponds","phone":"(03) 444-2343","city":null,"contact_name":"Ian Devling","contact_title":"Marketing Manager"},"units_in_stock":"29","units_on_order":"0","reorder_level":"10","category_id":"3","qty_per_unit":"32 - 500 g boxes","discontinued":"0","supplier_id":"7"}
```

Comment: Some other part of the script is echoing `16` before the PHP code you showed.

Comment: Are you doing `echo $_GET['product_id'];` before you call the `echo json_encode($product);` somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

You have some debug output in your php script or there is content before the opening `<?php` tag. The `16` in front of the json has to be removed. Find out where it comes from and remove it.